# Delphi dcc32 and manifest compilation

Tags: manifest, dcc32

How to compile a Delphi project using DCC32.EXE with the default manifest file?
I've compiled some project and the Task Dialog doesn't appear because of missing the manifest file.
When I compile from the IDE everything works fine but when I use the DCC32.EXE the Task Dialog component doesn't work.
I think the problem in the version info file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Create a file and name it `anything.xml`
2. Write the following into the file:
   `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
   <assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
     <assemblyIdentity type="win32" name="App" version="3.1.0.0"                 processorArchitecture="*"/>
     <dependency>
       <dependentAssembly>
         <assemblyIdentity type="win32" name="Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls" version="6.0.0.0" publicKeyToken="6595b64144ccf1df" language="*"     processorArchitecture="*"/>
       </dependentAssembly>
     </dependency>
     <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
       <security>
         <requestedPrivileges>
           <requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator"     uiAccess="false"/>
           </requestedPrivileges>
       </security>
     </trustInfo>
     <compatibility xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:compatibility.v1">
       <application>
         <!--The ID below indicates application support for Windows Vista -->
         <supportedOS Id="{e2011457-1546-43c5-a5fe-008deee3d3f0}"/>
         <!--The ID below indicates application support for Windows 7 -->
         <supportedOS Id="{35138b9a-5d96-4fbd-8e2d-a2440225f93a}"/>
       </application>
     </compatibility>
   </assembly>`
3. Create a resource file such as `proj_manifest.rc` and write the following line into it:
   `1 24 "anything.xml"`
4. Compile the resource file using brcc32.exe
5. Add the following line to the project source:
   `{$R 'proj_manifest.res'}`
6. Compile the project using the dcc32.exe and thats all.